# i try to build a solution that use the JQuery Ajax request to web page and fill the $scope object to pupulate the html template with the data

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

angular.module('spLists', [])

.factory('spListsFactory', function ($q) {

```
    return {            
                getItems: function (url) {

            var json, div = $('<div>').css('display', 'none').appendTo('body'); 
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            tab.load(url, function (data) {
                json = $(div.find('table')).tableToJSON();
                deferred.resolve(json);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
           }
           }

              // the controller 
             function empCtrl($scope, spListsFactory) {
                  spListsFactory.getItems(url)
                      .then(function (data){
                         $scope.employees = data;
                  });
               }
```

the problem is the data is loaded successfully but the scope object not populated with it

Comment: load executes parallel in another thread so this return `return deferred.promise;` will work before load callback function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify the scope in the angular execution context, using either $scope.$apply or my preference, $timeout. Try modifying your controller like this:

```
 // the controller 
 function empCtrl($scope, spListsFactory, $timeout) {
     spListsFactory.getItems(url)
         .then(function (data){
             $timeout(function() {
                 $scope.employees = data;
             })
         });
 }
```

Check out the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), specifically the section titled "Integration with the browser event loop".

EDIT:

Using $scope.$apply would look like this:

```
 // the controller 
 function empCtrl($scope, spListsFactory) {
     spListsFactory.getItems(url)
         .then(function (data){
             $scope.employees = data;
             $scope.$apply();
         });
 }
```

Comment: how to use the $scope.$apply in this solution